# Remove a table row after ajax success

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to remove a table row with fadeOut effect after a successful ajax call.

I tried it something like this, but it is not working.

```
//##### Send delete Ajax request to process.php #########
$("body").on("click", "#response table td a.del_button", function(e) {
    e.returnValue = false;
    var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split string (Split works as PHP explode)
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
    var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure   
    //console.log(myData); 

    $("#delete_this_user").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
         "Yes": function() {
            //$row.remove();
            $(this).dialog( "close" );

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                    url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                    dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                    data:myData, //Form variables
                    success:function(response){
                        //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                        $(this).closest('tr').find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
                            $(this).parents('tr:first').remove();                    
                        }); 
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        //On error, we alert user
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
         },
         "no": function() {
            $(this).dialog( "close" );
         }
      }
   });      


});
```

**UPDATE** - structure of my table row

```
 <tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' name='' value='' class='' />&nbsp;&nbsp;sdfsf</td>
  <td>sdfds</td>
  <td>fdsfs</td>
  <td><a href='#' id='edit-82' class='edit_button'><span class='edit_ico'></span></a></td>
  <td><a href='#' id='delete-82' class='del_button'><span class='delete_ico'></span></a></td>
 </tr>
```

Can anybody tell how can I do this?

Comment: Here the problem is `this` it does not point to anywhere near the tr

Comment: I tried it removing `this`. But result is same

Comment: no, the question is which is  the row that you want to remove, what is the pointer to it?

Comment: checked my updated question. It is the structure of the table row

Comment: which is the button clicked here? the one in the dialog or the one in the `tr`

Comment: there is a table on my page with lot of rows. In that table there a link in each row to delete users. when clicked on that link a dialog triggered to conform the delete. If the conformation is success I need to fadeOut the table row.

Comment: can you share how the confirmation dialog is opened? without it it will not be possible to get a reference to the row to be deleted

Comment: I updated question. There is dynamically generated ID for each delete link

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In this case we can create a closure variable to hold the reference to the row to be deleted

```
$("body").on("click", "#response table td a.del_button", function(e) {
    e.returnValue = false;
    var clickedID = this.id.split('-'); //Split string (Split works as PHP explode)
    var DbNumberID = clickedID[1]; //and get number from array
    var myData = 'recordToDelete='+ DbNumberID; //build a post data structure   
    //console.log(myData); 

    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr'); //here we hold a reference to the clicked tr which will be later used to delete the row

    $("#delete_this_user").dialog({
        resizable: false,
        height:140,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            "Yes": function() {
                //$row.remove();
                $(this).dialog( "close" );

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST", // HTTP method POST or GET
                    url: "process.php", //Where to make Ajax calls
                    dataType:"text", // Data type, HTML, json etc.
                    data:myData, //Form variables
                    success:function(response){
                        //on success, hide  element user wants to delete.
                        $tr.find('td').fadeOut(1000,function(){ 
                            $tr.remove();                    
                        }); 
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        //On error, we alert user
                        alert(thrownError);
                    }
                });
            },
            "no": function() {
                $(this).dialog( "close" );
            }
        }
    });      


});
```

Comment: thanks it worked, but why we need to hold a reference?

Answer (score 0):

```
<% for( var display of event) { %>
<%  var tId = display._id + "9"; %>
<tr id="<%= tId %>">
.....
</tr>`
<%  }  %>`$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/eventdelete',
      data: $('#deleteevent').serialize(),
      success: function(response){
         console.log(response.success);
         var tId = response.id + "9";
         document.getElementById(tId).remove();
         document.getElementById("CloseDelModalBtn").click();         
        }
      })
```

Comment: This is for ejs file. If you want you to make it has an HTML page.